# set value for textbox by clicking a value of table cell in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to set value for a textbox by clicking a value of table cell.i just confused how can i do it.
the table is generated by search data from database and when i click on any cell in the table that value will be set in another text box.this is the part of my code for table

**search.php**

```
$title=$_POST["title"];
$last_name=$_POST["last_name"];
$mobile=$_POST["mobile"];
$email=$_POST["email"];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE first_name='$title' AND last_name='$last_name' OR mobile='$mobile' OR email='$email'");

echo "<table class='datatable' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' id='example'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td id='first_name' class='clickable'>" . $row['first_name'] ."</td>";
  echo "<td id='last_name' class='clickable'>" . $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['mobile'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

The textbox i need to update is in another php page.so do i have any way to set the value for my text box?

Comment: where is the textbox to which the values have to be copied

Comment: Also the `td`s id is repeating in the loop, id should be unique - you can use a add a class like `first_name` instead of `id` to the `td` elements

Comment: If the "other php page" is a popup, you can do this.  Otherwise, you would have to leave the current page and either submit a form or go to the other page's url with a GET variable.

Comment: <input type="text" name="user" value="" id="user" /> this is the text box i need to set value from table.but this code is in another php page...

Comment: Was the search page opened with `window.open`?

Comment: *sidenote:* your code is subjected to SQL Injection attack, as you directly allow POST values to be inserted in your query.

Comment: You may be able to do it with polling too, but there may be a little lag and that's more complex then the solution I think you're looking for.

Comment: use [contenteditable](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable).

Comment: I feel like a fool for asking this because no one else has yet (so I feel like **I'm** missing something) but, where is your jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

search page is open via jquery..following is html code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
               function search(){
                            var title=$("#first_name").val();
                            var last_name=$("#last_name").val();
                            var mobile=$("#mobile").val();
                            var email=$("#email").val();


                            if(title!=""){
                            $("#result").html();
                            $.ajax({
                            type:"post",
                            url:"search.php",
                            data:'title='+ title + '&last_name='+ last_name + '&mobile='+ mobile + '&email='+ email,
                            success:function(data){
                                $("#result").html(data);
                                $("#first_name").val("");
                                $("#last_name").val("");
                                $("#mobile").val("");
                                $("#email").val("");

                                                           }
                          });
                      }

                 }

                  $("#button").click(function(){
                     search();
                  });

                  $('#first_name').keyup(function(e) {
                     if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                        search();
                      }
                  });

                  $('#last_name').keyup(function(e) {
                      if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                         search();
                       }
                   });

                  $('#mobile').keyup(function(e) {
                      if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                         search();
                       }
                   });
                  $('#email').keyup(function(e) {
                      if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                         search();
                       }
                   });





            });
        </script>
 <table class="datatable">
    <tr>
    <td width="100"><label for="first_name">First Name: </label></td>
    <td>
   <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" id="first_name" /></td></tr>
   <tr>
    <td><label for="last_name">Last Name: </label></td>
        <td>
   <input type="text" name="last_name" value="" id="last_name" /></td></tr>

   </table></fieldset>

   <fieldset>
    <table class="datatable">
    <tr>
    <td width="100"><label for="mobile">Mobile: </label></td>
    <td>
   <input type="text" name="mobile" value="" id="mobile"/></td></tr>

   </table></fieldset>

    <fieldset>
    <table class="datatable">
    <tr>
    <td width="100"><label for="email">Email: </label></td>
    <td>
   <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" /></td></tr>
      </table>
            <input type="button" id="button" value="Search"  />
             <ul id="result"></ul>
```